# He, together with she and I?

Tags: personal-pronouns, grammatical-case, prepositional-objects

How do you write the following sentence:

1. Marcelo, together with Angela and I, are going to...
2. Marcelo, together with Angela and myself, are going to...

Comment: If you remove Angela, would you write _I_? What's wrong with a simple _me_ instead of _myself_? Of course, if Marcello's is the only grammatical subject, he _is_ going. Together with Angela and me.

Comment: 'I' is wrong; 'are' is wrong; 'me' is correct. 'Myself' is not 'incorrect' but is a marked choice (for instance, in a formal register, for corrective emphasis if someone had just said 'Nobody will join in if Marcello and Angela are organising the production.').

Answer (score -1):

The example sentence does not combine *Marcelo* with *Angela* and *myself* as subjects. The sentence can be rewritten like this, which preserves the same grammatical meaning:

"Marcelo is going to ... together with Angela and me/myself".

*'together with'* introduces *Angela* and *myself* as indirect objects of the verb *going*.

However, if you write it like this:

"Marcelo, Angela and I are going to ... together.", the grammatical meaning changes somewhat, as *Marcelo, Angela and I* are *all* the subject of the sentence.

So in this case, *I* is wrong and *me* is or *myself* are both correct (gramatically). Differentiating between *me* and *myself* seems to be a matter of style.

Comment: _Angela_ and _myself_ are not objects of _go_.  _together with Angela and myself_ is a parenthetical (meaning that _Marcello_ is the lone subject of the matrix sentence, requiring ''_is_ going to ..." ). The (compound) preposition 'together with' selects the objective/accusative _me_ or _myself_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So are they arguments of the prepositional phrase or something? Can you clarify which part of my explanation is correct and which is not? Just asking so I can learn something myself, I'm not a native speaker :)

Answer (score -3):

He, she and I are joint subjects of the sentence, so you should use 'I' just as if you were saying "I am going to...".
The habit of using 'myself' instead of 'I' or 'me' is not correct English.

Comment: _John's going to Paris together with I_? Really? _John and I are going_, sure. But the example sentence is gramattically different.

Comment: So this is not the right answer?

Comment: I don't think it's correct to use "I" after the preposition "with". It may be part of the subject of the verb, but more immediately, it's the object of the preposition.